# How to parse the file name string from a file path in shell script?

Tags: shell, sh

I have files in directory  'new_kb'. I want to iterate on each file and execute a c++ binary on the file, like below:

```
kb_dir=./new_kb
for entry in "$kb_dir"/*
do
  echo "$entry"
   $file_name  = parse(entry)
  ./build "$file_name"/"$file_name".txt 
  done
```

One example of 'entry' is:

```
./new_kb/peopleObj.txt
```

from the variable path 'entry', I need to parse the string below out:

```
'peopleObj'
```

How to do this in a shell script?

Answer (score 1):

Using shell built in parameter expansion:

```
file_name=${entry##*/}
file_name=${file_name%.txt}
```

Using `basename(1)`:

```
file_name=$(basename "$entry" .txt)
```

Note that whitespace is fundamental to how shell commands are parsed, and all variable declarations should have no whitespace around `=`.

Comment: Worth noting that the *parameter expansions* are shell built-ins and avoid spawning a subshell that `basename` (from Linux coreutils) will require. This can provide substantial efficiency benefits if called within a loop (orders or magnitude depending on the number of iterations).

Answer (score 0):

Use `basename`

```
$file_name=$(basename $entry .txt)
```

Comment: Error: build.sh: line 5: =peopleObject: command not found